# SDDC Cast of literal value to 'generic' pointer

Tags: c

I am writing an at command for a radio module, I am trying to use the following function, however I cannot seem to pass anything for the 2nd argument that the compiler (SDDC) likes.

Function:

```
radio_receive_packet(uint8_t *length, __xdata uint8_t * __pdata buf)
```

My code:

```
static void
at_find(void)
{
    __xdata uint8_t mbuf[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH];
    // Cycle netID's 1-1000
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
    {   
        param_set(3, i);
        param_save();
        if (radio_receive_packet(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH, mbuf))
        {
            printf("Traffic found at %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    at_ok();

}
```

running this code produces the following error:

> radio/at.c:403: error 88: cast of LITERAL value to 'generic'
>   pointer
>  from type 'const-unsigned-char literal'
>  to type
>   'unsigned-char generic* fixed'

I've been slamming my head against a wall, I've used C before but not with SDDC or the xdata and pdata types. Also I have never been real strong with pointers and such. Any advice would be appreciated, Another section of the radio code uses this function exactly how I am, only the buffer is declared globally.

Comment: Which line is 403?  What's the definition of `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH`?

Comment: The function declaration is non-standard. It is lacking a return type.

Comment: @Olaf Sir I think that's not the case, OP has missed that while posting here. Did (not) you miss a `;` at the end, too?

Comment: Looks to me like it wants the address of an lvalue: uint8_t inOut; ..... inOut=MAX_PACKET_LENGTH; ...  radio_receive_packet(&inOut, mbuf);

Answer (score 4):

As per the function signature

```
radio_receive_packet(uint8_t *length, __xdata uint8_t * __pdata buf)
```

the first argument should be a pointer. In your case,

```
 if (radio_receive_packet(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH, mbuf))
```

it pretty much looks like a MACRO value, maybe of type `int` or `const-unsigned-char literal` whatever, but not certainly a `uint8_t *`.

*Hint: `__xdata uint8_t mbuf[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH];` Notice the array size.*

Comment: Yeah, looks like a #define to me too.  My guess is that it needs a pointer to a uint8_t so that it knows the buffer size, and can also return how many bytes it actually loaded into the buffer.

Comment: @MartinJames Can't agree more, sir. A very probable guess, I'd say. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend @SouravGhosh's answer with a solution: You should define a variable holding the buffer length at the beginning of your `at_find()` function:

```
uint8_t buffer_length = MAX_PACKET_LENGTH;
```

Then you pass a pointer to that variable as first parameter to the `radio_receive_packet()` function:

```
if (radio_receive_packet(&buffer_length, mbuf))
{
    [...]
}
```

So your problem seems to be with the first parameter and not the second parameter.